# Javascript random number generator to rotate Landing Page views

Tags: javascript, regex, function, file, recursion

I am currently developing a landing page that basically rotates and is multiplied by a number that generates an integer which is my LP-ID.

I am calling my views from folders that are named by numbers that start from 2 (2,3,4,n)

```
var xmapId = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 2 ) ) + 2;
```

As from the formula; xmapID would receive the numbers of either 2 or 3, which is cute compact and simple but very basic and I need to add features:

**1.)** A JS timer that would fade-in/out the views **in the xmapID var itself** (concated to the math.random and floor.)

**2.)** Making the formula recursive and more dynamic with regex: Since new folders with new views would be added regularly, I would need to use $n as a variable that would be looking for files with any prefix that looks like this:

```
xxxxxxx.ABC.jpg
```

or

```
xx.ABC.jpg
```

So anything before ABC.jpg should be ignored, how would that be written in regex formula?

Thank you.

> Clarifications & Edits:

I have a `var mapId =` I need to implement here 2 things:
1.) Regex: /(.*)([a-z]{4}.jpg)/gim
2.) and somehow point to `url: './textures/maps/'`

Afterwards it goes into this `var maps = generateXMap(   xmapId  , 100 );` the 2nd param isn't important and isn't called atm.

After that, a `function generateXMap( folderName, mapWidth ) {`

from that function there is an array:

```
var sudes = [
                    {

                        url: './textures/maps/' + folderName + '/wxyz.jpg',
                        attr#1: [ etc, etc],
                        attr#2: [etc, etc ]
                    },...,...];
```

Comment: So you just what to transform `xxxxxxx.ABC.jpg` to `ABC.jpg`?

Comment: I can't as i'm working with a windows app that provides me with those prefixes and suffixes. That why im trying to find a regex formula for this..

Comment: @ThomasAyoub - if you have a regex for this i'll appreciate it.

Comment: Still looking or my other answer fulfill your needs?

Comment: Include part of your code first, so I can catch up a bit more what you're trying to do

Comment: Please, when adding information, [edit] your question. Also, I'll need more context than that to help you

Comment: @ThomasAyoub - Edited.